# An animated movie about a black horse, set in early British industrial revolution

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

I am looking for an **old TV cartoon** probably from the **second half of the 1990s**.

The story is set in time of the British Industrial revolution. Story evolves around a black horse. I think there is a also a boy. The horse is sold and is forced to perform heavy labor.

I think the story integrated a classic theme - metaphorical transition from rural harmony to industrial nightmare. The image that stood out painted a nightmarish picture of the Black country, devilish industrial landscape through which this black horse is led. In the end the horse is rescued and united with the boy.

Comment: Sounds a bit like *Black Beauty* which was adapted many times. Possible animated candidates would be a [1987 Australian one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uD3cQ-hnxiE) and [one from 1999](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/black_beauty) (there was also a [Japanese one in 1995](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1119129/combined), but it doesn't seem to fit).

Comment: walt! you can add comment as answer. i checked it and it is version from the 80s that i had in mind. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the plot of [Black Beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Beauty), which was adapted many times. This particular one seems to be a [1987 animated version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Beauty_(1987_film)) from Australia. From [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Black-Beauty-DVD-Bob-Baines/dp/B0000649HB):

> 1987 Animated film, made by Burbank Films Australia, based on Anna Sewell's wonderful classic novel about the life and adventures of Black Beauty, a once proud and privileged horse in Victorian England who's life is changed for the worse when he is sold to a cruel new owner after his wealthy and kindly original owner loses his fortune.

Here are the last 8 minutes, showing some of the hardships the horse has to endure and finally reuniting with owner Polly: